# Why does the Microsoft JDBC driver ignore the failoverPartner host name

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

The Microsoft JDBC driver v4 seems to ignore the configured `failoverPartner` host name. The connection string looks a follows:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://primary-host:1433;database=ms-sql-db;failoverPartner=secondary-host
```

Yet, when the primary host is offline the driver is unable to connect to the secondary host:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host foo4711, port 1433 has failed
```

Notice how the host name in the exception does not match the host name in the connection string ('secondary-host' vs. 'foo4711'). 'foo4711' is the name of the physical machine while 'secondary-host' is the name the machine is listed under in `/etc/hosts`. 'foo4711' cannot be resolved to an IP in our setup.

So, why does the driver not use the host name given in the connection string?

Comment: It might be somewhat related to a similar problem I had: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12378514/148844. Try to give the instance name and also make sure the MSSQL browser service is running.

Comment: @Chloe, I did read your question before I posted mine but didn't think it was related.